# How to include field values in the vtypes message text for vtype validation in forms?

Tags: forms, validation, extjs, extjs3

I'm working on form validation and I have used Vtypes to check number ranges.

It's all working fine, except I need to include my own allowed values ( field.minValField and  field.maxValField) in the 'numberrangeText'. Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks in advance

```
     Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
            numberrange : function(val, field) {
                if(val < field.minValField || val > field.maxValField){
                    console.log(field);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            numberrangeText: 'Value Range Should Be: '

});
```

Arfeen

Comment: And by the way your numberrange function must `return true` if all ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to use templates or XTemplates in numberrangeText. Because they(extjs) just take this string without changes as I've found out from file `src/widgets/form/TextField.js` from the line `errors.push(this.vtypeText || vt[this.vtype +'Text']);`.

But as you can see you can use `field.vtypeText` instead.
For example you can write something like this:

```
field.vtypeText = 'Value Range Should Be: ' + field.minValField + '-' + field.maxValField;
```

in your `numberrange` function.

You can see what I'm talking about in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/CGaMV/3/)

Comment: Wouldn't this example be more clear? http://jsfiddle.net/CGaMV/25/  (Omitting the `numberrangeText` error message)